# Backbone + r.js. Making two different builds on one app on CoffeeScript

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript, requirejs, r.js

I have an issue to make two different builds on my app directory. I am using
**Backbone+CoffeeScript**, so it's a lot of staff in the folders.

I used `build.js` to generate one big `result.js` and load it on the page.

Now i want to make two different `router.coffee` files to include `router1.coffee` in one build(excluding `router2.coffee`) and vise versa to the other build.

Project structure:

```
app/
   models/
         model.coffee 
   collections/
         collection.coffee
   .............
   lib/
   settings.coffee
   router1.coffee
   router2.coffee
   main.js
   build.js
build/
   result.js
```

### My build.js:

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    name: "main",
    out: "../build/result.js",
    stubModules: ['cs', 'text'],
    exclude: ['coffee-script'],
    fileExclusionRegExp: /^views$/,
    preserveLicenseComments: false,
    optimize: "none",
    paths: {
      "cs"                 : "libs/cs",
      'coffee-script'      : 'libs/coffee-script',
      'jquery'             : 'libs/jquery-1.9.1',
      'jquery_ui'          : 'libs/jquery-ui.custom.min',
      'backbone'           : 'libs/backbone',
      'backbone-relational': 'libs/backbone-relational',

      //require.js dependency
      "requireLib"         : "libs/require"
    },
    shim: {
      'backbone': {
          deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
          exports: 'Backbone'
      },
      'underscore': {
          exports: '_'
      },
      'jquery_ui'         : ['jquery'],
      'fileDownload'      : ['jquery']
    },
    include: "requireLib"
})
```

How can i have **result1.js** with only **router1** included, and **result2.js** with only **router2** included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two `build.js` file, one for each router.